# How to navigate from component inside screen to another screen using react-navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So I have a file called `LoginScreen.js` that calls the component `PhoneLogin.js`. From `LoginScreen.js` I can run this code `this.props.navigation.navigate('App')` and the app properly navigates, however when I run that code from `PhoneLogin.js` I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

I believe this is because the component PhonLogin doesn't have the props of navigation, but how can I extend the props?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's missing the navigation prop. You have to pass it to your component from the parent. For example, if you're using JSX, `<PhoneLogin navigation={this.props.navigation} ... />`.

Comment: Thanks!! That worked flawlessly just without the "...".

Comment: Ah, that was just to indicate that you can pass additional props, see https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html for more.

Comment: Oh, ok! Thank you very much then.

Comment: Someone has been systematically going through my profile and downvoting all questions and answers I've provided on Stackoverflow. The admins seem to be content letting it happen as well. Therefore, I would ask that any subsequent visitors of this post please vote genuinely and leave a comment explaining why you did or did not find the post useful. I'm not trying to indulge in some pathetic tit-for-tat, I just want to help the next person. Thank you!